# Get a Javascript variable on the click of button

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

That's my code:

```
afficherListe();
function afficherListe()
{
 $.post('afficher_liste.php', function(data)
 { 
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    if(data!="")
    {
        $.each(obj, function(index, value){
            $('<li><button onclick="supprimer_article()">X</button>'+value.nomArticle+' '+value.prixArticle+'</li>').insertAfter($('#liste_boissons'));
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('no data');
    }
 }); 
}

function supprimer_article(article_selectionne)
{
    alert(article_selectionne);
}
```

**Problem** : I want to put my variable in `supprimer_article()` function, to have it in parameter and to continue my work in the function. 
Example : If I click on "X" Vodka button (view picture), I would find in`alert(article_selectionne);` "Vodka"

In a primary step, I've put the variable like that :
`$('<li><button`**onclick="supprimer_article('+value.prixArticle+')"**`>X</button>'+value.nomArticle+' '+value.prixArticle+'</li>').insertAfter($('#liste_boissons'));`

But, the result in `alert(article_selectionne);` was : UNDEFINED

If you think you have the solution, it would be very nice and helpful to share it for me !

To have an idea of what do this function now (the final goal is that this function will remove the selected article from the DB after the onclick event....) :

[image]

Comment: I would upvote your question, but I cannot do that until your question is edited (these are rules of this community). So, if you edit your question in any way, I will upvote your question and you will have 15 reputations.

Comment: Okay, but which question are you talking about ? (my comment or my post) @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add name to function arguments when calling. Replace the line

```
$('<li><button onclick="supprimer_article()">X</button>'+value.nomArticle+' '+value.prixArticle+'</li>').insertAfter($('#liste_boissons'));
```

with the following code:

```
$('<li><button onclick="supprimer_article(\'' + value.nomArticle + '\')">X</button>'+value.nomArticle+' '+value.prixArticle+'</li>').insertAfter($('#liste_boissons'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the value within the function itself. Change:

```
$('<li><button onclick="supprimer_article()">X</button>'+value.nomArticle+' '+value.prixArticle+'</li>').insertAfter($('#liste_boissons'));
```

to

```
$('<li><button onclick="supprimer_article('"+value.nomArticle+"')">X</button>'+value.nomArticle+' '+value.prixArticle+'</li>').insertAfter($('#liste_boissons'));
```

Comment: You need to hardcode `value.nomArticle` in DOM string, not like you did. What you did is wrong HTML syntax.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE thanks for highlighting the error

Comment: Thank's for your responses, I tried your solution jeff but it isn't correct, it displays no data. @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE I don't understand what I have to do for **hardcode value.nomArticle in DOM string** ?